# Mostrando div com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde, quero mostrar o conteudo dentro de cada div desse for, porém não to conseguindo:

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
        ?>
        <div class="cada-texto">
            <a href="">titulo <?= $i ?></a>
            <div class="conteudo">
                texto texto <?= $i ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#mostra').click(function(){
            //mostra div
            $('.cada-texto').show();

          });
          $('#fecha').click(function(){
            //oculta div
            $('.cada-texto').hide();

          });
     });
</script>
```

**Eu clico nos links gerados pelo codigo em php, e continua sem mostrar nada.**

Comment: De todas as divs de uma só vez?

Comment: Ao clicar nela, exibir o que tem dentro

Comment: Cada div tem um botão "mostrar" "esconder" ou são só 2 botes pra mostrar ou esconder tudo?

Comment: So quero que quando clique no link, eu consiga ver a div

Comment: no link "titulo"? Mas as divs já vem escondidas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture o clique no `<a>` e alterne em *mostrar/ocultar* a cada clique.

> A classe `.conteudo` deve estar `display: none;` no seu CSS.

Basta usar apenas uma função pra isso, e colocar `e.preventDefault();` para que o `href` do `<a>` não redirecione a página:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.cada-texto a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var el = $(this).next();
       el.is(':visible') ? el.hide() : el.show();
    });
});
```

```css
.conteudo{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cada-texto">
   <a href="">titulo 1</a>
   <div class="conteudo">
       texto texto 1
   </div>
</div>

<div class="cada-texto">
   <a href="">titulo 2</a>
   <div class="conteudo">
       texto texto 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro checa para ver se $('#fecha'), $('#mostra') não estão voltando vazios (só para garantir que os ids estão corretos.

No div que vc quer esconder coloca:

```
style="display: none;"
```

Para exibir continua com show(), e esconder  hide() do jeito você está fazendo hoje.

Comment: como verifico isso?